# Play 2.x Static assets not found

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am not sure why my public assets are not being discovered by play. i am using the same code that works in an activator template in a play2 intelliJ project.

the routes

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET    /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

and the html

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at(s"images/foo.png")" width="64px">
```

seem to be correct, and the foo.png is in the `public/images` folder. the inspector highlights `images/foo.png` in the html with "cannot find" message. they seem to be being compiled, as they also correctly are placed in the target directory. the rest of the app and html is working fine

what is a possible explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@routes.Assets.versioned("images/foo.png")
```

Honestly, I have no idea why but I know that it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, there was nothing wrong. it seems that between sbt, play, and IntelliJ, there was simply lag in the resource resolution. after about an hour, everything suddenly worked.

this may not be reproducible, and therefore this question might be a candidate for removal